# Android Studio Build Error After Upgrading Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build, build.gradle

After upgrading to Android Studio `1.3.1` yesterday, Getting this error when building projects, I cannot create a new project. Adding error and build.gradle file below :

[image: Error]

[image]

Alredy tried changing `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolVersion` to `21`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every major revision of the Support Library, such as the `23.0.0` AppCompat you are using, compiles against the API level of the same number: i.e., API 23 as per [this G+ post from the AppCompat developer](https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes/posts/ekKcJwtCW9U). Therefore to use `23.0.0`, you must update your `compileSdkVersion` to 23.

Note this is completely different from *targeting* API 23 (which can be done separately and is what is required to use the runtime permissions model).